# $\alpha$ variation of identity map

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following problem.

Let $\alpha$ be a number in $(0,1)$. Suppose $\pi=\{0=x_1<\cdots <x_n=1\}$ is a partition of $[0,1]$. Consider the sum $V_\pi=\sum_{k=1}^n|x_{k}-x_{k-1}|^\alpha$. Does $V_\pi$ converge to a finite number when the mesh size $|\pi|:=\max_{k}|x_k-x_{k-1}|$ shrinks to 0?

While it is easy to verify that the answer is "yes" when the partition has uniform mesh size, I don't know an argument that works for general partition $\pi$.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it so very easy to verify with uniform mesh size? What if I take $\alpha=1/2$ and the standard partitions $x_i=\frac{i-1}{n-1}$? Then, making your sum range for $V_\pi$ agree with your choice of labels for the $x_i,$ we get
$$V_\pi=\sum_{k=2}^n \sqrt{x_k-x_{k-1}}=\sum_{k=2}^n \sqrt{1/(n-1)}=\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n-1}}=\sqrt{n-1}$$
which does not converge as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for your answer. I should have checked my calculation more carefully before posting.

Comment: No worries! It can be very surprising how many surprises lurk in real exponentiation years after we think we're familiar with $\Bbb{R}$.